# Get absolute position of an Image in a PDF with Apache PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to get the absoluto position of an image inside a PDF document using Apache PDFBox.

I have used a method I have seen in many code pages, but I always get position 0,0 for all images in the page. I suppose they are relative positions, but how can I get the absolute position of the images?

In a document of only one page, I always get position (0,0) for all images while they are in different positions inside the page.

I get

```
Image [Image7]
position in PDF = 0.0, 0.0 in user space units
raw image size  = 100, 100 in pixels
displayed size  = 1.0, 1.0 in user space units

Image [Im2]
position in PDF = 0.0, 0.0 in user space units
raw image size  = 107, 108 in pixels
displayed size  = 1.0, 1.0 in user space units

Image [Im3]
position in PDF = 0.0, 0.0 in user space units
raw image size  = 107, 108 in pixels
displayed size  = 1.0, 1.0 in user space units
```

The method code I am using can be seen also here in stackoverflow

```
protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands)
          throws IOException
  {
    String operation = operator.getName();
    if( "Do".equals(operation) )
    {
      COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
      // get the PDF object
      PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );

      // check if the object is an image object
      if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
      {
        PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

        System.out.println("\nImage [" + objectName.getName() + "]");

        Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
        float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();

        // position of image in the PDF in terms of user space units
        System.out.println("position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
        // raw size in pixels
        System.out.println("raw image size  = " + imageWidth + ", " + imageHeight + " in pixels");

        // displayed size in user space units
        System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in user space units");
      } else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
        PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
        showForm(form);
      }
    } else {
      super.processOperator( operator, operands );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I assume you have not registered the listeners for the operators which change the current transformation matrix. Have you?

Comment: Could be. What operators do you mean? Please, could you set an example or a link to a page where I could see and example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java